# C# - LINQ - specific query select

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to get a specific select with the best performance possible

I currently have a code like this:

```
var getData = from x in dbContex.MyTable
                                            where x.Car == "audi"
                                            select x;
```

MyTable has three columns:
Car
ProductionYear
Color

I would like to download a specific vehicle brand with the year of manufacture that has a specific color.

I am currently doing it with reference to the code above:

```
 foreach (var item in getData)
                {
                    if (item.color == "blue") item.ProductionYear = "1999";
                    if (item.color == "red") item.ProductionYear = "2003";

        // etc (...)
                }
```

I would like to assign a specific year for a given car and color if I find it.

A very prosaic example above.

Problem - I currently have 100 colors and only want to check 10 colors.

How can I do it faster so as not to search the entire list and not to use IF statements?

Comment: LINQ is not designed to change anything. As I see it, you want to change the year of an element depending on what colour it has

Comment: Crate an array of the 10 colors you want.  Then check if color is contained in the array : if(myColorArray.Contains(item.color) && if(item.ProductionYear == "1999"))

Comment: @jdweng he want to change year, not check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of the colors, then use `Contains` method in the predicate expression:

```
var colors = new [] { "red", "blue" };

var results = dbContext.MyTable
    .Where( x => "audi" == x.Car
        && colors.Contains( x.color ) );
```

Then use a switch statement to assign your years:

```
foreach(var car in results)
{
    car.ProductionYear = car.color switch
    {
        "blue" => 1999,
        "red" => 2003,
        _ => // unexpected result, throw exception
    }
}
```

You could also define the years with the colors then work the year assignment into the LINQ query:

```
var colorYears = new []
{
    new {
        color = "red",
        ProductionYear = 2003,
    },
    ...
};

var colors = colorYears.Select( x => x.color ).ToArray();

var results = (...query from above...)
    // enumerate
    .ToArray()
    // join datasource results with your colorYears array
    // on the `color` property
    .Join( colorYears, 
        c => c.color, 
        cy => cy.color,
        ( c, cy ) => 
        {
            // assign the configured production year for the color
            c.ProductionYear = cy.ProductionYear;
            // return the entity
            return c;
        } );
```

Comment: Don`t you think that way will have much more comparisons rather that switch withot filtering?

Comment: @moho I specified a class with colors and I refer to it in a switch statement, but I get the error "A constant value is expected"

I do not want to hardly enter the color but refer to the place where I already have them defined

Comment: @TomProjectID_23 as the error stated, you need to use constants for the cases in the switch statement/expression.  I updated my answer earlier with such a scenario using the `Join` method to return the entities with the updated `ProductionYear` properties

Comment: @Moho - yes, everything is fine, I was wondering how to bypass the fixed color assignment - I asked the last question in the new post below - will you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

There is no scenario, where you don`t use if or switch clause. You want to change data, which is not LINQ case. Only thing I would do - go to switch, rather than If clause.

Comment: This is not true, you can create a dictionary that maps color to a year and use that instead of if statements or switches.

Comment: @juharr, hm, really. I think, much better to say is "There is no scenario, where you don`t iterate".

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to create a new thread so I will write here - a question about LINQ of course and data comparison in the array

I have this code:

```
 var dataTest = (dbContex.MyTable.Where(x => x.col1 == str1
          && x.col2 == str2 && x.col3 == str3).Select(x => x.ID ).FirstOrDefault());
```

I want to check if there is such a row for these three fields and get its ID - everything is fine when I have values, but when any field is NULL - it cannot compare it and returns information that there is no such record.

the goal is to check if there is a duplicate with these values ​​in MyTable based on these three fields - except that each of these fields can be NULL

how best to compare NULL?